# 12.04 LTS not able connect to internet when installed, but could connect using LiveCD before installation

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, live-cd

I met a strange problem. When I use LiveCD to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I was able to connect to Internet through wired connection, choosing "Try Ubuntu".

But when I installed it, it could not connect:

ifconfig -a shows that eth0 does not have inet address

I added:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to `interfaces`, then restart networking, it says:

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces...
Failed to bring up eth0
```

I tried to set static ip, but still no connection.

I tried to delete 70-persistent, but still no connection.

I tried to reinstall network driver, but still no connection.

What can I do? Thanks.